# How to write override methods in Java

Tags: java, overriding

This is part of a homework assignment.

I am trying to make a `class` named `RomanNumeral` that has several methods. The first method, `RomanNumeral` checks whether a string `rn` is a Roman Numeral or not. The second method converts the Roman numeral into a decimal value. My problem lies with the rest of the methods. I am asked to create an override file for `.equals()`, `.compareTo()` and `toString()`. My question is how would I even begin doing this? What does it mean to override? Am I supposed to look at what they do, and emulate it? And if I am, where can look at the method that defines `.compareTo()` or `toString()`?

I can post my current code if it helps.

Comment: Override basically means to replace the code of a defined method with your own...`@Override`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html take a look at the documentation

Comment: What books or docs have you consulted so far? They must be really bad if they don't explain what override means ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, from what I can see, you have 2 main questions here.

1. What does it mean to override a method?
2. How to I override a method?

Lets think up a new class, so that I can avoid doing your homework for you.

We have a class called Student, that stores 3 Strings.

- First Name
- Last Name
- GPA

It might look something like this.

```
public class Student {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String gpa

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String gpa){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    // Perhaps some methods here

    public String getIdentity(){
        return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName;
    }
}
```

You like the Student class, but you decide that it would be much better if you could keep track of a College studentId as well. One solution would be to extend the Student class.

By extending the class, we get access all of the methods (and constructors) that Student had, and we get to add some of our own.
So lets call our new class CollegeStudent, and add a String for the studentId.

```
public class CollegeStudent extends Student{

    String studentId;

}
```

Now, with no additional work, I can create a CollegeStudent, and get it's identity.

```
// Code
CollegeStudent myCollegeStudent = new CollegeStudent("Dennis", "Ritchie", "2.2");
String identity = myCollegeStudent.getIdentity();
// Code
```

Ok, enough setup. Lets answer your questions.

So lets assume that instead of returning "Ritchie, Dennis", you would prefer getIdentity() to return the "studentId" for that college student. You could then **override** the getIdentity method.

By overriding the method, you will get to re-write getIdentity() so that it returns the studentId. The CollegeStudent class would look something like this.

```
public class CollegeStudent extends Student{

    String studentId;

    @Override
    public String getIdentity(){
        return this.studentId;
    }
}
```

To override a method, you must return the same type of object (String in our example), and you must accept the same parameters (our example did not accept any parameters)

You can also override constructors.

So how does this apply to your assignment?
.equals(), .compareTo(), and .toString() are already defined because of the classes that you will be extending (such as Object). However you will want to re-define or **override** those methods so that they will be useful for your class. Perhaps **your** implementation of toString() will return the word "four" instead of "IV". Probably not, but the point is that you now have the freedom to decide how the method should be coded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what does the this. statement do? Does this.firstName = firstName; in the first method assign the parameter firstName of method Student to the class variable firstName?

Comment: I could have instead written the constructor's header as "String Student(String fname, String lname, String newgpa)" and so the assignment for the first name would look like "this.firstName = fname". I use "this" to reduce ambiguity.  If the names of the variables are different, then "this" is not necessary. I.e. in this new scenario "firstName = fname" would also work.

Answer (score 2):

When one class *extends* another, it *inherits* all of its non-private instance members.

For example, `RomanNumeral` *extends* `Object`, so it *inherits* the latter's `toString()` method. This means that you can call `toString()` on any `RomanNumeral` instance, and it will call the `Object.toString()` method.

However, `RomanNumeral` can choose to *override* this method by providing its *own* definition, that will supersede the one it inherited. Then, when you call `toString()` on a `RomanNumeral` instance, it will call the method that you defined. (This works even if you're referring to the `RomanNumeral` instance via an `Object` reference.)

So, you are being asked you to flesh out this rubric:

```
public class RomanNumeral {

    // ... your other methods ...

    @Override       // this line is optional
    public String toString() {
        // TODO define this method
    }

    @Override       // this line is optional
    public boolean equals(Object o) { // note: 'Object', *not* 'RomanNumeral'!
        // TODO define this method
    }

    @Override       // this line is optional
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO define this method
    }

}
```

Note that, despite what you seem to have been told, there is no such thing as an "override file". The above methods are defined inside `RomanNumeral.java`, just like any other method.

Comment: All members are inherited, not only methods. Package visible members are only inherited if the subclass is in the same package.

Comment: @zeroflagL: Re: Fields: indeed; but since they can't be overridden, and in general are more confusing, I decided not to mention that. (I don't think my answer implies that they *aren't*, does it? It just doesn't mention them.) Re: package-visible members: Sort of. It's complicated. They *are* inherited, as you can see by creating a new subclass in the original package. By contrast, private methods are never inherited: if `Foo` has an inner class `Bar` that's a subclass of it, then `Bar` can *see* `Foo`'s private methods, but can't override them, can't use them on itself without an upcast, etc.

Comment: Someone completely new to this area could indeed imply that fields are not inherited.
Me: "Package visible members are only inherited if the subclass is in the same package"
You: "They are inherited, as you can see by creating a new subclass in the original package"
What's the point of repeating what I wrote?

Comment: @zeroflagL: I *didn't* repeat what you wrote; I *contradicted* it. Suppose that `pkg1.ClassA` has subclass `pkg2.ClassB`, which has subclass `pkg1.ClassC`. Then `pkg1.ClassC` will have all of `pkg1.ClassA`'s package-private methods -- which proves that `pkg2.ClassB` must have inherited them, too. `pkg2.ClassB` can't see them, call them, or override them, but it *does* pass them on to its own subclasses. (But as for the fields thing: O.K., I've now changed 'methods' to 'members'.)

Comment: What makes you think that ClassB is involved when ClassC calls a method of ClassA?

Comment: @zeroflagL: `ClassC` can override the methods that it inherited, via `ClassB`, from `ClassA`. These overrides will be called whenever a non-overridden `ClassA` method invokes one of those methods.

Comment: ClassC does inherit the methods in question directly from ClassA, not from ClassB. ClassB does not pass them on. Take a look at some Javadocs and you will see what I mean. And you surely will not doubt Oracle, will you?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):
An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

The ability of a subclass to override a method allows a class to inherit from a superclass whose behavior is "close enough" and then to modify behavior as needed. The overriding method has the same name, number and type of parameters, and return type as the method it overrides.

When overriding a method, you might want to use the `@Override` annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a method in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

To override means to change the behaviour of instances by creating a new implementation of a method. Every Java class inherits equals(), hashCode() and toString() from the class Object.

Try to write new implementations of these methods in your class so toString() returns the RomanNumber as letters, equals() to return if the other object is als a RomanNumber and has the same value and respect the contract that two equal objects need to have the same hashcode.

Add an @Override annotation to your methods, to mark them as deliberate change and so let the compiler check the signature.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is redefine those methods:

```
public class RomanNumeral implements Comparable<RomanNumeral>{

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
// your conditions and return true or false
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Show the world my representation";
}

public int compareTo(T o) {
/* your conditions and if returns:
Less than zero -> instance precedes obj in the sort order.
Zero -> instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as obj
Greater than zero -> instance follows obj in the sort order)*/ 
}
```